Is there a way to make Automapper work in AOT build/release?
We use automapper.data in our project and it works quite well. Now I am experimenting the idea of publishing our project in AOT mode, After adding these in our project file and run our code
<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<PublishAot>true</PublishAot>

We got this error
runtime automapper error
so looks like automapper.data won't work in AOT mode, is there a way to walk around this, so automapper.data can run in AOT?
I am hoping automapper and Automapper.data can work in AOT

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

AutoMapper heavily use reflection and IL emit. The aot support have been discarded by the maintainer, unless someone to pay for it. You will need to look for alternative like https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster or https://github.com/riok/mapperly

This is a question about AM.Data, not the main repo. Do the alternatives do what AM.Data does?

As AutoMapper.Data depends on AutoMapper, it will not work either. Mapster and mapperly does not seem to support IDataReader. They recommand to use Dapper to do the mapping from sql directly. (See https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT for aot support)

many thanks, looks like the case
